# Create a temporary password Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, password, login

How do you create a password in Windows Sever 2008 that forces the user to change said password on login? I'm creating the accounts for our team and would like people to change from the random password I generate for them.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a local user:

[image: local]

Or, a domain user:

[image: domain]

Comment: Where is that screen?

Comment: @TylerDeWitt Which one?  For local users, run `lusrmgr.msc`.  For domain users, run `dsa.msc`.  Both screens are from the "New User" dialogs within those tools.

Comment: @TylerDeWitt the first screen is in Control Panel > User Accounts (or alternatively in Control Panel > Admin Tools > Computer Management > Local Users and Groups). The second screen (domain user) is located under the Users Properties in Active Directory Users and Computers

Comment: If the user accounts already exists you can access this option under the Account options section on the Account tab of the user properties.